# ul list key navigation breaks/malfunctions when focussing out

Tags: jquery, html

I have a ul list that is generated by an ajax live search, for that list I want to make a key navigation and so far I have this code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      //on focus when arrow down is pressed
      $("#s").focus(function(){
        $("#s").keydown(function(e){
          if(e.which === 40){ //on arrow down
            if($('ul#searchresults li').length >= 1){ //if has one or more li
              if(!$('ul#searchresults li').hasClass('liSelected')){ //if has selected class
                $('ul#searchresults li:first-child').addClass('liSelected');
              } else {
                $('ul#searchresults li.liSelected').next().addClass('liSelected');
                $('ul#searchresults li.liSelected').first().removeClass('liSelected');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });


       $("#s").focusout(function(){
          $('ul#searchresults li.liSelected').first().removeClass('liSelected');
       });

    });
```

Here the html:

```
<form role="search" method="get" autocomplete="off" id="searchform" action="http://localhost/site/" class="searchbar-nav">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search game">
    </div>
</form>

<ul id="searchresults" class="searchresults">
   <li id="101" class="liSelected">Mirror's Edge Catalyst</li>
   <li id="95" class="">Minecraft</li>
   <li id="106" class="">Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor</li>
</ul>
```

What this does is: when I focus on that input with id #s and press the arrow down key it gives the selected class to the first item, if no li contains the selected class and if it does then it will add the selected class to the next li and remove it form the li that had the selected class previously. This works perfectly.

But when I focus out and focus back in it just malfunctions and I don't know why. When I press the arrow down key it won't do the same, it won't jump to the next li and usually get stuck.

I was hoping somebody what function I'am missing and what is causing this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you add the portion of HTML that includes a sample of your results UL? Wondering how that is structured in relation to the form

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot, I put the ul list in edit now, thank you

Comment: No problem :] actually now that I think of it, it didn't have an impact on the solution sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is just that the keydown event is being bound each time the search box gains focus. To prevent that from happening, you can simply unbind when focusout occurs.

```
$("#s").focusout(function(){
    $('#s').unbind('keydown');
    $('ul#searchresults li.liSelected').first().removeClass('liSelected');
});
```

I also got a little carried away and made some modifications in a jsfiddle. One of the major changes I made that I thought could be useful was just to store the current selection of the list in a variable. By doing this, you can run some of your logic checks against a var instead of performing jQuery lookups each time. This could help you performance-wise. It should also be shareable between different types of keys being pressed - like up arrow. Anyways, here it is if you like, https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/nxfgvjdg/4/

Comment: Wow thanks man this is it! There's a lot I can learn from the code you presented, thanks I am forever grateful for this, my man!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :]